# Solving simultaneous equation when one changes the other

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> You have two points given by $(w,x)$ and $(y,z)$. Can $(w,x)$ be
>   transformed into $(y,z)$ by only performing the operations $(w+x,x)$
>   and $(w,x+w)$? $w,x,y,z$ are integers greater than or equal to $1$.

I thought this was a simple system of equations:

> $w+a\times x = y$
>
> $x+b\times w = z$

Given $w,x,y,z$ we can solve for $a$ and $b$, check if there integers or not and be done. However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Consider, $w=1, x=3, y=2, z=1$